# Interpreting lower part of an uint64_t as float

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a data stream that I get from a device. The chunks are 8 bytes, which I read as `uint_64t` words. A few of the higher bits are flags (not all 4 bytes) that define the type of data. Some, but not all, of the chunks have the lower 4 bytes representing a `float` in binary representation.

How do I correctly extract that part into a `float` variable?

Let word be {4-byte flags, 4-byte float [LSB]}.

This "seems" to work:

```
float extracted = *reinterpret_cast<float *>(&word);
```

Yet, the compiler (GCC 10) with '-Wall' warns about type-punning

> warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing
>   rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]

for optimization levels >= -O2.

I suspect I'm doing all sorts of evil here and don't
feel comfortable with the warning.
What's the correct way doing this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want the lower bytes you'll need to treat that as `float[2]` won't you?

Comment: "A uint64_t word is encoded such that the lower 4 bytes are a float in binary representation" - what makes you think that?

Comment: Sorry, if the question was misleading.
This is a data stream that I get from a device.
The chunks are 8 bytes a few of the higher bits are flags (not all 4 bytes),
that define the type of data.
"Some", not all, of them have the lower 4 bytes encoded in the way I described in the question.

Comment: No need to use a `uint64_t`, you can use a struct with the proper members and so get rid of the aliasing problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type punning *may* "work" in your compiler, but it is really frowned upon by the C++ standard.  `memcpy()` (or equivalent) is really the only option the standard supports, eg:

```cpp
// note that casting a pointer-to-type to a pointer-to-char for
// purposes of accessing the type's raw bytes IS allowed by the
// C++ standard...
uint64_t word = ...;
uint32_t flags;
float extracted;
std::memcpy(&flags, &word, sizeof(flags));
std::memcpy(&extracted, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&word)+sizeof(flags), sizeof(extracted));
```

Or:

```cpp
#pragma pack(push, 1) // or equivalent
struct flags_and_float
{
    uint32_t flags;
    float value;
};
#pragma pack(pop) // or equivalent

uint64_t word = ...;
flags_and_float ff;
std::memcpy(&ff, &word, sizeof(ff));
float extracted = ff.value;
```

Comment: Thanks to you and the many other insightful posts.

Why do I need a reinterpret_cast in std::memcpy?
Isn't that implicitly casted to void* anyway?

`std::memcpy(&extracted, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&word)+sizeof(flags), sizeof(extracted));`

Comment: "*Why do I need a reinterpret_cast*" - for the **pointer arithmetic** that is being used *before* `memcpy()` is called. The starting memory address of `word` is casted to `char*` **and then incremented by 4 bytes**, that new address (the address of the `float`) is what gets passed to `memcpy()`.  Notice the 1st `memcpy()` is not using `reinterpret_cast`, because it is using the starting memory address of `word` (the address of the `flags`) as-is.

Answer (score 2):

To comply with the strict-aliasing rules, it would be helpful to read your data stream as `unsigned char` (or `std::byte` if you can use C++17) that you analyze and parse in groups of 8. The rules have an exception that allow reinterpreting byte data (`char`, `unsigned char`, and `std::byte`) as another type. So call the data a sequence of bytes until you know how you want to interpret it.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to get rid of the warning cast the address to void * before the cast to float *.

```
float extracted = *static_cast<float*>(static_cast<void*>(&word));
```

So long as you know that the referenced bytes really do hold a float this is fine.

Comment: This does not get rid of the warning.

Comment: Try `char*` instead of `void*`.  The standard has explicit exceptions for casting data using `char*` pointers.